# Can you use richtextbox selectionchanged to look for doubleclick event?

Tags: c#, silverlight, richtextbox

I am trying to find a way to get the selected text of a richtextbox once a word is double clicked.  The richtextbox is setup like :

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="rtbStoryLine" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="0,15,16,17" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="25" IsReadOnly="True" MaxWidth="700" MaxHeight="130" ToolTipService.ToolTip="This box displays the selected line below." SelectionChanged="rtbStoryLine_SelectionChanged" />
```

I add text to the code behind like:

```
public void AddTextt(string text2Add)
{
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    Run r = new Run();
    r.Text = text2Add;
    p.Inlines.Add(r);
    rtbStoryLine.Blocks.Clear();
    rtbStoryLine.Blocks.Add(p);
}
```

In the selection change I want to check if there was a double click and then do something with the highlighted word.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use mouse `DoubleClick` event and then compare the selection with the previous one stored in some variable. It seems more reasonable than trying to detect `DoubleClick` event from `SelectionChanged`. Rgds, AB